# Slot filling corpora

Tags: semantics, corpora, parts-of-speech

I was wondering if anyone knows of slot filling corpora such as ATIS. I tried finding ATIS but since I am not a member of LDC I couldnt get access to it. Do you know of any place where I can find a copy of ATIS or similar corpus?

Comment: Try also: Open Data SE, r/opendata and r/datasets

Answer (score -1):

Please check these github repositories:

[hongyunnchen/JointSLU](https://github.com/hongyunnchen/JointSLU/tree/master/data)
[yvchen/JointSLU](https://github.com/yvchen/JointSLU/tree/master/data)

Comment: This is a "link only" answer and cannot stand as it is. Can you add information about the data one can expect behind the github links (title, authhor, size of the datasets, some description)?